# LiFi with Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, ldr

I am trying to learn LiFi by transferring data between two Arduino UNO boards with sample code as in link below.

https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/hamiran1997/li-fi-system-36ff5b?f=1#comments

Transmitter code seems to be working with LED blinking at faster rate, and light in LDR also blinks.
However on the receiver i am not getting the data printed. I used the same code as in this project, except for using Arduino UNO rather Nano. Could anyone please help or direct me to some sample LiFi Arduino code.
I am using LM393 LDR sensor to detect light signals.

Comment: Posting your actual schematic/wiring and your code are really required to answer this question.

Comment: Also, there are some other projects for LiFi on Arduino. You can start off from the Github searching for them: https://github.com/search?q=lifi+arduino

Comment: My wiring and code are exactly same as in the above link.

Comment: The project you linked **does not** use an LDR. Note that someone else has reported that it **doesn't work**. Show us your **actual** schematics.